# loading shows on all buttons of mapped items in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, api, react-query

I am mapping the comments and replies of comments arrays with array.map().

```
  {data.comments?.map((comment) => (
        <CommentsSection
          user={user}
          token={token}
          thread={data}
          key={comment._id}
          comment={comment}
          threadRefetch={threadRefetch} />
      ))}
```

The loading comes from react-query in the CommentSection component:

```
const {
   data: commentRes,
   refetch: commentR_Refetch,
   isFetching: Loading,

 } = useQuery(['/comment-reply-thread', thread._id, user?.username, token],
   () => comment_reply_thread(
     user?.username, thread._id, comment._id, token, crMessage
   )}
 });
```

Here is the input field code with button and button converts to loading

```
 <FormControl>
      <InputGroup size='md'>
        <Input value={crMessage} onChange={(e) => setCrMessage(e.target.value)} placeholder='Reply...' />
        <InputRightElement >
          <SendButton isLoading={Loading} onClick={() => commentR_Refetch()} aria-label='' />
        </InputRightElement>
      </InputGroup>
    </FormControl>
```

here is the image

[image]

How to make loading only the clicked button. Any solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. sending a reply should likely be a mutation, not a query.
2. you are using `comment._id` inside your `queryFn`, but it's not part of your `queryKey`. That's likely the reason why states are shared - because they are all using "the same" query.